# How to configure a Rails app to work with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I folow this tutorial (http://excid3.com/blog/setting-up-ubuntu-12-04-with-ruby-1-9-3-nginx-passenger-and-postgresql-or-mysql/#.UaEsAmRqM4E) and I get all ok. But when I put my ip in the browser I get a message "We're sorry, but something went wrong" I have tryed apache2 and I have the same error.

Comment: This is an application error (500). Check your logs. It's possible your appserver is configured correctly and the rails application is crashing.

Comment: I fix the error was a database error, now the problem that I have is to see the logs. Because the logs of /opt/nginx/logs/error.log doesnt show the same information if I use rails s in the ruby app. Tanks shellion